# Huge .svg. How to open in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, svg

After upgrading to 20.04, I cannot open big svg files. I get:

> XML parse error: cannot load more than 200000 XML elements

Problem occurs in Image Viewer and Gimp, while ImageMagick `display`, inkscape, `libreoffice --draw`  stall, showing nothing.

Firefox and Chrome open the file, but Firefox's zoom is poor and Chrome is very slow and tends to stall.

svg packages: `apt list --installed | grep svg`

```
gir1.2-rsvg-2.0/focal-updates,now 2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libimage-librsvg-perl/focal,now 0.07-8build5 amd64 [installed]
libqt5svg5/focal,now 5.12.8-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
librsvg2-2/focal-updates,now 2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
librsvg2-2/focal-updates,now 2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed]
librsvg2-common/focal-updates,now 2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
librsvg2-common/focal-updates,now 2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
librsvg2-dev/focal-updates,now 2.48.9-1ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: With what application? Inkscape?

Comment: I believe that this is a limitation of librsvg. Do you have one of the failing svg files that you can post online for experimentation?

Comment: The xml can be pruned by had btw: https://dev.to/adammckenna/how-and-why-to-clean-svg-markup-49i

Comment: Does Inkscape also exhibit this?

Comment: Please add output of `grep ^deb -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` to the question or to pastebin.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TqZ1xwxk

Comment: You are missing necessary repository components. Add the `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted`,  `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted` and `deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and retry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in `librsvg` package. They have 200000 items [hardcoded](https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/librsvg/-/commit/17b178499f03f5d22194331ee2c462bdbebe1c49) for versions prior 2.49.5.

I can confirm the bug on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. So I have reported it to LaunchPad as [bug 1916055](https://pad.lv/1916055). Popular affected apps:

- Eye of GNOME
- Eye of MATE, Atril
- GIMP

There are apps using different libraries and fail - Karbon, Krita, Cenon.

Possible workarounds are:

- recompile the library locally with patch to have 1000000 XML node limit.

  At first enable Source Code repositories from `software-properties-gtk` and the run commands below to get build-dependencies and for patching with successful compilation:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository main
  sudo apt-add-repository universe
  sudo apt-add-repository multiverse
  sudo apt-add-repository restricted

  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

  sudo apt-get build-dep librsvg2-dev
  sudo apt-get install devscripts

  cd ~/Downloads
  apt-get source librsvg2-dev
  cd librsvg-2.48.9

  # change 200000 to 1000000
  sed -i "s/200_000/1_000_000/" rsvg_internals/src/limits.rs
  dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc -us

  sudo apt-get install ../*svg*.deb
  ```

  Then pin package versions with single long command:

  ```
  cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-librsvg2
  Package: gir1.2-rsvg-2.0
  Pin: release a=now
  Pin-Priority: 1337

  Package: librsvg2-2
  Pin: release a=now
  Pin-Priority: 1337

  Package: librsvg2-bin
  Pin: release a=now
  Pin-Priority: 1337

  Package: librsvg2-dev
  Pin: release a=now
  Pin-Priority: 1337

  Package: librsvg2-common
  Pin: release a=now
  Pin-Priority: 1337

  Package: librsvg2-doc
  Pin: release a=now
  Pin-Priority: 1337
  EOF
  ```

  And enjoy:

  [image: EoM with patched librsvg2]
- use viewers and editors with different back-end library:

  - web browsers like Firefox, Chromium, Konqueror
  - LibreOffice Draw
  - Inkscape (needs >14 Gb of RAM)

Comment: You have to fix your repositories. Then run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to get newest dependencies. I ran this method on fresh Ubuntu 20.04 LTS without problems.

Comment: after removing conflicting files: sudo rm /usr/share/doc/librsvg2-2/changelog.Debian.gz
 sudo rm /usr/share/doc/librsvg2-common/changelog.Debian.gz I think is fine now. thx

Comment: I hit what it seems is the same issue with the output of `systemd-analyze dot | dot -Tsvg > systemd.svg`, but only have 20k lines. On browsers works fine